# Compute the "best of 4" average per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to find the average of the best `n` out of `N` cells for each row in a pandas dataframe?

See the dataframe below, where I want to find the average of the best 4 scores out of 6 (n=4, N=6):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'stu1' : [17,19,12,17,13,13], 
               'stu2' : [20,18,15,17,15,0], 
               'stu3' : [16,19,0,16,0,0],
               'stu4' : [0,0,0,0,0,0],
               'stu5' : [0,8,14,0,7,9]},
               index = 'q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6'.split()).T
```

The average of the best 4 of `st1` would be based on the following values: 17, 19, 17, 13 and be 16.50. For `st3` is would be based on 16, 19, 0, 16, resulting in 12.75.

How to calculate this for all rows?

Comment: Your math is off, please re-check those averages.

Comment: thx, match should be right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Rubik's Cubing

```
df.stack().sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(4).mean(level=0)

stu4     0.00
stu3    12.75
stu5     9.50
stu1    16.50
stu2    17.50
dtype: float64
```

Comment: `nlargest` will work without sorting: `df.stack().groupby(level=0).nlargest(4).mean(level=0)`. Bonus: you also get to keep the order.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort your columns per row, then take the best 4 simply by slicing. From there, computing the mean is straightforward:

```
np.sort(df)[:,-4:].mean(axis=1)
# array([16.5 , 17.5 , 12.75,  0.  ,  9.5 ])

pd.Series(np.sort(df)[:,-4:].mean(axis=1), index=df.index)

stu1    16.50
stu2    17.50
stu3    12.75
stu4     0.00
stu5     9.50
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding the option using `np.partition`. If your data is big, `np.partition` is better than `np.sort`.

```
np.partition(df, len(df)-4)[:,-4:].mean(-1)

Out[1230]: array([16.5 , 17.5 , 12.75,  0.  ,  9.5 ])
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case `rank`

```
df[df.rank(1,method='first',ascending=False)<=4].mean(1)
stu1    16.50
stu2    17.50
stu3    12.75
stu4     0.00
stu5     9.50
dtype: float64
```